# After login get blank page only in chrome

Tags: symfony, apache2

I look at this chapter in cookbook to write a login procedure.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

In firefox is everything fine. But in google chrome i get a blank page after login. In my error log exists following lines.

```
[Thu Feb 19 09:26:06.502498 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17203:tid 140244355569408] [client 192.168.56.1:4441] Premature end of script headers: , referer: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
[Thu Feb 19 09:26:06.502888 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17203:tid 140244355569408] [client 192.168.56.1:4441] AH01070: Error parsing script headers, referer: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
[Thu Feb 19 09:26:06.504918 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17203:tid 140244355569408] [client 192.168.56.1:4441] AH01068: Got bogus version 84, referer: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
[Thu Feb 19 09:26:06.507243 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17203:tid 140244355569408] (22)Invalid argument: [client 192.168.56.1:4441] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (passing brigade to output filters), referer: http://app.dev-local/app_dev.php/login
```

I have following version:

- Symfony 2.6
- PHP 5.5.16
- Apache/2.4.10
- Ubuntu 14.04

Have someone the same issue? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your config_prod.yml and config_dev.yml. Search for:

```
    chromephp:
    type:  chromephp
```

and remove/comment that block. Example:

```
          #    chromephp:
          #    type:   chromephp
          #    level:  info
```

I think Chrome adds supplementary information in headers sent.